# How to implement the “parent-to-child” navigational transition as prescribed by Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, transition

How to implement the “parent-to-child” navigational transition as prescribed by [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#navigational-transitions-parent-to-child)

Comment: Your question is duplicated, and you can find "Parent2Child" animation examples by searching from google or github

Comment: https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: https://medium.com/@david.gansterd/bringing-smooth-animation-transitions-to-android-88786347e512